# dose regexp_replace can not use multi regexp(|) in postgresql? Otherwise what should I do?

Tags: regex, postgresql, regexp-replace

```
select regexp_replace('"Tho"mas""', '"$|^"', '');
```

got `Tho"mas""`, but I want `Tho"mas"`

however...

```
select regexp_split_to_array('"Tho"mas""', '"$|^"')
```

got `{"","Tho\"mas",""}`, it is not so bad. then why these two regexp works diffrent?

Answer (score 0):

Use the global (`g`) modifier, so that all matches not just the first match are processed:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('"Tho"mas""', '"$|^"', '', 'g');
```

`regexp_split_to_array()` already matches globally by its nature since it's supposed to split the entire string.

Comment: Thanks, I should read the [document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) more carefully:

"Flag **i** specifies case-insensitive matching, while flag **g** specifies replacement of each matching substring rather than only the first one. Supported flags (though not g) are described in Table 9.23."